# Getting an error "Installed Flash Player is not a Debugger"

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have upgraded the flash player from 9 to 11, so i have got an error that it is not the debugger version. so how to overcome that situation i have to use flash player 11 for my application and i am using adobe Flex Builder 3.0. Here i am showing you the error when i debug the application. Please Help me.

[image]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you downloaded the debugger version of Flash Player? It's available [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). Download the "content debugger" version.

Comment: Thanks Ranhiru Cooray.. It solved my problem.. Thanks again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have solved that question with the help of Ranhiru Cooray. The Link provided by Ranhiru Cooray in the Comment is very helpful and i have just download the 2 things and install

1) Download the Windows Flash Player 11.2 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE)
2) Download the Windows Flash Player 11.2 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers)

now error doesn't comes and i have solved that issue.

Comment: Thanks! For me I had to install:
1. [Windows Flash Player 11.7 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE)](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_ax_debug.exe)

2. [Windows Flash Player 11.7 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers)](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.exe)